# Is there an equivalent of "this" in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Basically I have this code:

```
$file = $web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx")
$file.CheckOut()
```

and I was wondering if there is anyway to use a pipe and the powershell equivalent of `this` to rewrite it as:

```
$web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx") | $this.CheckOut()
```

When I try this I get the error:

> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.

I also tried using `$_` instead of `$this` but got the same error.

Comment: Good question, Abe!  This bit me a few times when I first started messing around with PS.

Comment: For functions within a class, use `$this` to reference the instance of the given class that is calling the given function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking for is `$_` and it represents the current object in the pipeline.  However you can only access `$_` in a scriptblock of a command that takes pipeline input e.g.:

```
$web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx") | Foreach-Object -Process {$_.Checkout()}
```

However there are aliases for the Foreach-Object cmdlet {Foreach and %} and -Process is the default parameter so this can be simplified to:

```
$web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx") | Foreach  {$_.Checkout()}
```

One other point, the GetFile call appears to return a single file so in this case, the following would be the easiest way to go:

```
$web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx").Checkout()
```

Of course, at this point you no longer have a variable containing the file object.

Answer (score 14):

Actually there is a $this in a few cases.  You can create a ScriptProperty or ScriptMethod and attach it to an object, and $this will be the original object.  You can then define these in types files (I'd recommend using the module [EZOut](http://ezout.start-automating.com), it makes life much easier) so that any time you see that type, you get that method.

For example:

```
$Web  | Add-Member ScriptMethod EditFile { $this.Checkout() }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#this

Answer (score 1):

`$_` is the variable for "current object" in powershell.

However, you aren't passing any data, this is just variable assignment.  You can only use the pipeline if you manipulate the actual output of a command and use it as input down the pipeline.

I think what you want can be accomplish with nested parentheses:

`($web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx")).CheckOut()`

In PS, anything you put inside parentheses gets treated as its own object, and you can apply methods to that inline without variable reassignment.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment does silence the default output, but it does not prevent an object from being further referenced.

```
($file = $web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx")).CheckOut()
```

Of course, it's much more common to **either** store the return value in a variable and do stuff with it **or** chain methods/properties/pipes.